# Correct way to use Promise in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

I have got a method:

```
public get(): Promise<Study[]> {
return this.http.post('', data, options)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => { console.log(response) }) // response.json().result as Study[]
      .catch(this.handleError);
}

private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
    console.error('getStudyPlanView: ', error);
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }
```

Is it correct way to use Promise?
I call promise like as:

```
this.planningService.getStudyPlanView(this.globalModel.schoolId, this.globalModel.studyPeriodId)
      .then(result => { })
      .catch((error => console.log('ERROR loadStudyPlan():' + error)));
```

Why I need to use `.then` in `public get()`? and is there difference where to write `.toPromise()`? Below or above?

I think I do something wrong cause I get an error after request promise:

> Service.ts:82 get:  SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Comment: Maybe return just `response.result`? without json()?

Comment: `.then(response => { console.log(response) })` will resolve your promise with `undefined`

Comment: The "correct" way to use a Promise in Angular is to use Observables instead. LOL. If you would like to see an example of using an Observable with http in Angular, let me know and I'll post the code as an answer here.

Comment: Please, share a good example, how to use, I will accept answer. Also I want to know how to use chain of calls using Observable

Comment: Your handleError method doesnt need to return a promise rejection. The toPromise method should reject on error (so you are catching the rejection already).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example service using Observables:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

import { IProduct } from './product';

@Injectable()
export class ProductService {
    private _productUrl = './api/products/products.json';

    constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

    getProducts(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
        return this._http.get<IProduct[]>(this._productUrl)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
        // in a real world app, we may send the server to some remote logging infrastructure
        // instead of just logging it to the console
        let errorMessage = '';
        if (err.error instanceof Error) {
            // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
            errorMessage = `An error occurred: ${err.error.message}`;
        } else {
            errorMessage = `Server returned code: ${err.status}, error message is: ${err.message}`;
        }
        console.error(errorMessage);
        return Observable.throw(errorMessage);
    }
}
```

And here is the component method call:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this._productService.getProducts()
            .subscribe(products => {
                this.products = products;
                this.filteredProducts = this.products;
            },
                error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer, I will educate this and after will accept, ok? But why I still get an error?

Comment: What does your JSON data look like?